# Name of unsigned literals in clause normal form

Tags: logic, terminology, clause, conjunctive-normal-form

The elements of a logical statement in clause normal form, are called literals.

For example, given the clause `{a, !b}`

The literals are `a` , `!b`.

But suppose you want to obtain the set of elements regardless of whether they are negated.

The 'unsigned literals'(?) are `a` , `b`.

What would be a better/more standard term than 'unsigned literals'? One could say 'variables' I suppose, but that seems incongruous in a context where they could be constants, or complex terms in their own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best available answer seems to be 'atoms' as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_formula - though the objects in question could be complex terms, they are atoms from the perspective of propositional logic.